# convert partition from MBR to GPT

Tags: disk

I created extended partition for windows and now I want to convert this partition from MBR to GPT. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the main challenges that we face while converting MBR to GPT is that conversion is possible from MBR to GPT, only if there are no partitions or volumes present in the disk. 
So, before you start, ensure there are no partitions on your disk. If there are, follow these steps:

- Create a complete Backup of your disk partitions and Data.
- Right click on **Start Menu >> Command Prompt (Admin)** to open a command prompt with elevated privileges
- On the prompt screen, type `diskpart` and hit the  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
- Type `list disk` to obtain the list of disks
- Note down the number/id of the disk you wish to convert into GPT. Once you have it, type the command: `select disk <id>`. Once, you hit the  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you would receive a notification stating that your disk is now selected.
- Finally, type in `convert gpt` to convert your disk into GPT

Once your disk is converted, you can recreate your partitions and restore the data.

Comment: It's worthwhile to warn new users that this procedure, done properly, will destroy all data on the entire disk. The first step ("Create a complete Backup") is very important if those family photos or term papers are important to you. Sometimes new users (unwisely) skip steps that they do not understand.

Comment: Thank you for emphasizing on the BACKUP point @user535733